# Returning common chars

Tags: c, arrays, string, while-loop

My code is supposed to compare 2 strings and returns the common characters in alphabetical order. If there are no common chars, it will return a null string.

However the program is not running.

Code

```
void strIntersect(char *str1, char *str2, char *str3)
{
int i,j, k;
i = 0;
j = 0;
k = 0;
while(str1[i]!='\0' || str2[j]!='\0')
{
    if(strcmp(str1[i],str2[j])>0)
    {
        str3[k] = str1[i];
        k++;
    }
    else if (strcmp(str2[j],str1[i])>0)
    {
        str3[k] = str2[j];
        k++;
    }
i++;
j++;
}
}
```

Example

```
Input string 1:abcde
Input string 2:dec
Output: cde
```

How do I get it to work?

Comment: You are describing what the function is returning... but the return type is `void`, it's not returning anything. Also, I think `||` in the condition of the `while` should be `&&` instead.

Comment: `strcmp` compares 2 strings, not single characters, so `strcmp(str1[i],str2[j])` should give you a warning or error.

Comment: This question is about set intersections; not string comparison, and can be done in O(n+m) (where `n` and `m` are the length of the two strings respectively, assuming you're not interested in multi-byte characters.

Comment: You need a `main` function that calls your function `strIntersect`.

Comment: "the program is not running" is not a helpful description of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A option is to iterate over the complete second string for each character in the first string

```
int i = 0;
int k = 0;
while(str1[i] != '\0') {
    int j = 0; 
    while(str2[j] != '\0') {
        if (str1[i] == str2[j]) {
           str3[k] = str1[i];
           k++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

I replaced the `strcmp` because you are comparing single characters not a `string`

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems with your code

1. `strcmp` is not needed for a simple char comparison
2. Is the 3rd char string allocated by the caller?
3. Your approach won't work if source strings are either of different sizes or are not alphabetical.

My solution assumes that input is ASCII, and is efficient (used a simple char array with indexes denoting ASCII value of the character).
If a character is found in `str1`, the char map will have a 1, if it is common, it will have a 2, otherwise, it will have a 0.

```
void strIntersect(char *str1, char *str2, char *str3)
{
  int i=0, j=0, k=0;
  char commonCharsMap[128] = { 0 };

  while(str1[i] != '\0')
  {
    commonCharsMap[str1[i++]] = 1;
  }

  while(str2[j] != '\0')
  {
    if(commonCharsMap[str2[j]] == 1) 
    {
      commonCharsMap[str2[j++]] = 2;
    }
  }

  for(i=0; i<128; i++)
  {
    if(commonCharsMap[i] == 2)
    {
      str3[k++] = i;
    }
  }
  str3[k++] = '\0';
}

int main() 
{
  char str1[] = "abcde";
  char str2[] = "dce";
  char str3[30];
  strIntersect(str1, str2, str3);

  printf("Common chars: %s\n", str3);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is *exactly* how this should be solved, and I was going  to type this up until I saw your answer. The only difference i would add is including `limits.h` and using `1 << CHAR_BIT` for the lookup array dimension (and, of course, size limits on `str3` and an additional argument). I sincerely hope the OP sees this answer, as I suspect this is how it was likely intended to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your if case and Else if case are identical and you are just comparing elements according to your Index. i.e you are comparing first element with first, second with second and so on. This won't provide you solution. I suggest use two for loops. I will provide you code later if you want